# What is the difference between EnterUpgradeableReadLock and EnterReadLock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When I read the C# Multithreading, I'm confused about what is the difference between EnterReadLock and EnterUpgradeableReadLock
In the code below, can replace cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock() with cacheLock.EnterReadLock()?

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private Dictionary<int, string> innerCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public AddOrUpdateStatus AddOrUpdate(int key, string value)
{
    //can there be cacheLoack.EnterReadLock?
    cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
    try
    {
        string result = null;
        if (innerCache.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            if (result == value)
            {
                return AddOrUpdateStatus.Unchanged;
            }
            else
            {
                cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    innerCache[key] = value;
                }
                finally
                {
                    cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
                return AddOrUpdateStatus.Updated;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                innerCache.Add(key, value);
            }
            finally
            {
                cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            return AddOrUpdateStatus.Added;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"can replace cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock() with cacheLock.EnterReadLock()"_ no. Because you enter a writelock while holding the upgradable readlock. If it wasn't upgradable, you couldn't do that.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock?view=netframework-4.8 I think the remarks section explains it sufficiently well.

Comment: ReaderWriterLockSlim was optimized to be as cheap as possible, it is not "recursive" by default.  In other words, you can acquire a lock just once on the same thread.  That's a problem if you are reading and also want to write, if it isn't upgradable then you'd deadlock yourself.  Otherwise easy to diagnose, it throws a LockRecursionException if you get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade to a write lock it must be an upgradeable lock.

Why not just always use an upgradeable lock? What's the downside? This:

> Only one thread can enter upgradeable mode at any given time. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterupgradeablereadlock?view=netframework-4.8)

This is a critical problem in your code. Since you are always taking the lock in this mode even when just reading you effectively have single-threaded access to the data structure. Effectively, it's no longer a reader writer lock at all.

I understand it is your intention to allow concurrency in the common read case while achieving safety in the write case. Maybe the easiest fix is to first try reading from the cache in read mode. If a write turns out to be required exit the lock completely and retry in upgradeable mode or directly in write mode. That way the fast path has concurrency.

That said I wonder what kinds of real world scalability `ReaderWriterLockSlim` has. Your locked code region is very cheap. The internal data structures of the lock might become contended and all scalability might be destroyed. It might end up being just as fast or slower than `Monitor`/`lock`.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is designed to scale out across keys. This is probably the way to go.